# pasar objeto php a funcion javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy arreglando incidencias de un `e-commerce` que no desarrolle y me encontré con el siguiente problema: cuando el usuario realiza la búsqueda de algún producto y arroja el listado, si quieres ordenar o filtrar por mayor o menor precio lo único que hace la pagina es un *submit* y no me arroja resultados. Hay una función en otro fichero `PHP` que está esperando el parámetro que le pasa el botón un vez que lo clickeas pero no lo esta recibiendo. lo que necesito es pasarle el value del botón al objeto. la linea del botón es esta:

```
<input type="button" name="" value="Menor Precio" id="boton1" onclick = "Asignar_Filtro('Menor Precio');">
```

y lo que intente desarrollar yo es esto:

```
<?php

    function AsignarFiltroPHP(VaFiltro)
    {
    $variable=post('filtro');
    $variable=VaFiltro;
    echo $variable;
    }
?>  

<script>
    function Asignar_Filtro(valorFiltro){
        AsignarFiltroPHP(ValorFiltro);
        var variableJS= <?php AsignarFiltroPHP(); ?>;
    }
</script>
```

Mi idea era guardar en una variable `PHP` el valor del objeto "post('filtro')" en una variable para después devolverlo dentro de la etiqueta JavaScript en la variable dentro de la función JavaScript y luego pasarle a dicha variable el valor del parámetro que trae del botón y de esa forma que se ejecute el reordenamiento de los items. me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Para recibir algo por POST en PHP debes ponerlo así `$_POST['namedelinput']` con post('filtro') no recibirás nada.

Comment: en realidad post('filtro') es el nombre del objeto que necesito llenar con el value del imput. lo que necesito es pasarle el valor del value del boton a ese objeto post('filtro') para que ingrese e un swich que tengo en el otro fichero. me explico?

Comment: ya que usas javascript porque no intentas pasar directamente mediante "XMLHttpRequest" hacia el php deseado : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713078/5215609

Comment: `$variable=post('filtro');
    $variable=VaFiltro;` asignas dos valores distintos a `$variable` al final siempre valdrá `VaFiltro`. Si quieres que se sumen o concatenen debes poner `.=` en la segunda `$variable`.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un par de cosas que entender antes:

PHP es un lenguaje de servidor por lo que este se procesa en el servidor antes de mostrar el sitio web, y en este caso Javascript actúa como lenguaje de cliente, por lo que con esta información ya procesada y el resultado como html se ejecuta en el navegador del usuario el código javascript.

Es por esto que por mas que el código este en el mismo archivo, se ejecutan en contextos distintos y no comparten informacion en ningun momento.

Por lo que "enviar una variable PHP" en realidad significa tenderizer esta informacion como parte del html desde el servidor" pero este no puede ser llamado desde javascript como pretendes como `AsignarFiltroPHP(ValorFiltro);` ya que la función php solo existe en el servidor y al ejecutar el código javascript el html seria algo como.

```
<html>
    <script>
        function Asignar_Filtro(valorFiltro){
            AsignarFiltroPHP(ValorFiltro);
            var variableJS= ""; 
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Donde AsignarFiltroPHP, se renderiza como tal y desde el lado del cliente se espera que sea una función javascript